# int permutations in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to implement a method with the following signature:

```
public int Max(int number){ }
```

Comment: @SMA - it is not about Max and it is not about int :) - clearly clear question... More readable form - "Given sequence of digits find permutation that represent largest integer value".

Comment: user7007558, amount of effort spent solving problem that is demonstrated in the post will likely lead to a lot of downvotes on the post. In general if you can't solve problem that looks like basic interview question - check interview questions&solutions sites first...

Comment: I think that the downvotes is due to a bad statement of the question. I've suggested an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not most efficient way is to cast to string and order desc

```
var result = int.Parse(String.Join("", digit.ToString().OrderByDescending(x => x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The largest number that can be created by a digits of a given number is obtained by ordering the digits from largest to smallest. See the following code for a possible implementation.

```
    public int Max(int number)
    {
        var numberAsCharArray = number.ToString().OrderByDescending(c => c).ToArray();
        var largestNumberAsString = new string(numberAsCharArray);
        return Int32.Parse(str);       
    }
```